# Finding next element with while loop python

Tags: python, loops, nlp

im stuck with this idea. Id like to print the verb that come just right after the noun of pronoun so i'm iterating , until the loop find a verb. then print it. But it seems to print me not just verbs but also other elements.
Any idea were i could go wrong ? thank you so much

```
 points = [('I', 'PRON', 'nsubj'),
         ('don', 'AUX', 'aux'),
         ('t', 'PART', 'neg'),
         ('hope', 'VERB', 'ROOT'),
         ('that', 'SCONJ', 'mark'),
         ('the', 'DET', 'det'),
         ('salary', 'NOUN', 'nsubj'),
         ('will', 'AUX', 'aux'),
         ('change', 'VERB', 'ccomp'),
         ('.', 'PUNCT', 'punct')]

for i, (word, pos, dep) in enumerate(points):
    intermediate_list_sentences = []

    if pos == "PRON" or pos == "NOUN":
        iterate = 1
        while points[i+iterate][1] != "VERB":
            iterate+=1
            print(points[i+iterate][0])
```

> OUTPOUT DESIRED => HOPE

Comment: Can you please explain the expected output and the logic to get there?

Comment: Your description and desired output makes no sense. You state ``verb that come just right after the noun of pronoun``, but neither ``hope`` nor ``change`` are *right after* a (pro)noun. And why would you want ``hope`` and not ``change``? Side note: de-denting the print will give you the verbs that come after a (pro)noun, but not "right" after. Please clarify.

Comment: yes sorry I mean that come after noun or pronoun . And yes , after the second loop its supposed to be change

Comment: Well, then simply de-dent/unindent the print, then it will print "change" and "hope". Indentation is an important part of the Python syntax.

Comment: oops... you are right TT I feel silly now , thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your code, you just have to `print` the word *after* you skipped all the non-verb words, not the non-verb words themselves, i.e. move the `print` out of the loop:

```
while points[i+iterate][1] != "VERB":
    iterate+=1
print(points[i+iterate][0])
```

Alternatively, you could create an `iter` from the list of words and use two nested `for` loops iterating *that same* iterator:

```
it = iter(points)
for word, pos, dep in it:
    if pos in ("PRON", "NOUN"):
        print(word)
        for word2, pos2, _ in it:
            if pos2 == "VERB":
               print(word2)
               break
```

Or more concise, using `next` to get the matching `VERB`:

```
it = iter(points)
for word, pos, dep in it:
    if pos in ("PRON", "NOUN"):
        verb = next((word2 for word2, pos2, _ in it if pos2 == "VERB"), None)
        print(word, verb)
```

Output:

```
I hope
salary change
```